# Trouble with a php code that adds a log in/log out button

Tags: php

I wanted to add a log in/log out button to my menu, so I added the following php code to my child themes function.php:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );

function add_loginout_link( $items, $args ) {

  if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {

   $items .= '<li><a href="'. wp_logout_url( get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) ) .'">Log Out</a></li>';

  }

  elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {

   $items .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '">Log In</a></li>';

  }

  return $items;

}
```

It worked great except that it added the log in/log out button right up against the woocommerce $0.00. For example (log in$0.00) How could I put a space between the two like this (log in $0.00)

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Well, you *could* put a space after the "Log In" text in your code, but a much better solution is to use CSS - You can add  `margin-right` or `padding` to the link.

Comment: I tried adding a space in the text but it doesn't work. Would I have to redo the whole code in CSS? I'm not a coder so I have no idea!

Comment: The space should work (even though its not the ideal solution). Where did you put it? Also, no you don't need to redo the whole CSS, you just need to add a new rule for this. However I'm not familiar with WooCommerce (I on'y use Wordpress itself) so I've no idea where this is code it added or what classes etc it has to target it. If you can include the HTML for that section of the page (rather than the code - the CSS works on the HTML), I should be able to show you what you need for the CSS.

Comment: In the .php, I added a space to the text like this >Log In < and >Log Out <. I'll see if I can find the CSS for that page. Actually, it's in the header.

Comment: the space is probably only part of what you will end up wanting to style there. You should add a class to the `a` or `li` element and add relevant css rules in your style.css file

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the space is a bad idea.

Here is the code you would need with a space for the login:

```
$items .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '">Log In </a></li>';
```

seems a simple solution.

IF you want to try css, it's relatively simple as well.

change the same line to this instead:

```
$items .= '<li><a class="custom-nav-link" href="' . get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) . '">Log In</a></li>';
```

then in your css add this line:

```
.custom-nav-link {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Obviously you could change the 15 to any value you want.  Repeat for the logout.  But you don't need to add the css again.

Comment: That did the trick! Just adding the space in the .php didn't work for me, but changing the .php and adding the css did it! Thanks so much @rudtek!

Comment: No problem.  Mind checking the question as answered?